# Sparse array with O(1) indexing and O(1) prev and next

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I want to implement data structure with operations both pertinent to arrays - i.e. indexing, and linked list - quick access to prev/next item. Resembles sparse array, but the memory is not a concern - the concern is time complexity.

Requirements:

- key is integer with a limited range `1..N` - you can afford to allocate an array for it (i.e. memory is not a concern)

Operations:

- `insert(key, data)` - O(1)
- `find(key)` - O(1) - returns the "node" with data
- `delete(node)` - O(1)
- `next(node)` - O(1) - find next occupied node, in the ordering given by key
- `prev(node)` - O(1)

I was thinking of implementation in an array with pointers to the next/prev occupied item, but I have problems in the `insert` operation - how do I find the prev and next items, i.e. the place in the double linked list where to put the new item - I don't know how to make this `O(1)`.

If this is not possible please provide a proof.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean. The next item in an array is index+1, the previous item is index-1. Do you want a linked list on top of an array? Can you provide an example of how the data structure would be used?

Comment: @dtb nope, see the question: next means next *occupied* node. And I want anything that fulfills the given requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with a [Van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree).

The tree supports the operations you require:

> ```
> Insert: insert a key/value pair with an m-bit key
> Delete: remove the key/value pair with a given key
> Lookup: find the value associated with a given key
> FindNext: find the key/value pair with the smallest key at least a given k
> FindPrevious: find the key/value pair with the largest key at most a given k
> ```

And the time complexity is O(logm) where m is the number of bits in the keys.

For example if all your keys are 16 bit integers between 0 and 65535, m would be 16.

EDIT

If the keys are in the range 1..N, the complexity is O(loglogN) for each of these operations.

The tree also supports min and max operations, which would have complexity O(1).

- Insert O(loglogN)
- Find O(loglogN)
- Delete O(loglogN)
- Next O(loglogN)
- Prev O(loglogN)
- Max O(1)
- Min O(1)

### DETAILS

This tree works by using a large array of children trees.

For example, suppose we had 16 bit keys.  The first layer of the tree would store an array of 2^8 (=256) children trees.  The first child is responsible for keys from 0 to 255, the second for keys 256,257,..,511, etc.

This makes it very easy to lookup to see whether a node is present as we can simply go straight to the corresponding array element.

However, by itself this would make finding the next element hard as we might need to search 256 children trees to find a nonzero element.

The Van Emde Boas tree contains two additions that make it easy to find the next element:

1. A min and max is stored for each tree so it is O(1) work to see whether we have reached our limits
2. An auxiliary tree is used to store the indexes of non-zero children.  This auxiliary tree is a Van Emde Boas tree of size the square root of the original size.

Comment: Peter, so the time complexity is `O(log log N)`? But please specify time complexity *for which operations*? Please update your answer, providing time complexity of each operation, taking into account that the key range is `1..N` (i.e. using `N` in the expressions)

Comment: If we treat `N` as a constant, all operations will always be `O(1)` - no matter which data structure we pick (because `key` would then be bounded by a constant, so there wouldn't even be any unbounded variables involved anymore). So I don't think it's constructive to view `N` as a constant.

Comment: Suppose I was inserting n items (all with keys in range 1..N), and chose to store them in a simple unsorted array.  Wouldn't the complexity of such a data structure be O(n) not O(1) even if N was a constant?

Comment: @sepp2k who said `N` is viewed as a constant?

Comment: "complexity of such a data structure" - that term doesn't make sense. do you mean the total complexity of a sequence of operations (in this case, inserting)?

Comment: @Tomas I was referring to this: "You have stated that your keys are integer with a limited range, so this becomes O(1)".

Comment: @Karoly Sorry - I meant the complexity of finding a single element in an unsorted list is O(n) if there are n elements in the list.

Comment: sepp2k is right but I think for almost all practical cases you can treat loglogN as constant.

Comment: Thanks @sepp2k you are correct! Peter, you wrote exactly that! Please reconsider this and don't consider `N` being a limited constant. Will this somehow change your answer?

Comment: I've edited the answer to give the complexity in terms of the size of the keys.  I agree with sepp2k that this is the most constructive way to view the complexity.

Comment: Peter, you still have the problematic sentence there. Please clean up the answer to contain the necessary information in as few characters as possible (i.e., high signal to noise ratio :-))